# How to show video thumbnails in Google search result?

Tags: html, search-engine, thumbnails

[image]

There results in google that show video thumbnails, I found some meta code in some site:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://kinoprofi.net/9527-palmy-v-snegu-2016.html">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://s.kinoprofi.net/s/2016-03/1458636506_palmy-v-snegu-1.jpg">
    <meta property="image_src" content="http://s.kinoprofi.net/s/2016-03/1458636506_palmy-v-snegu-1.jpg">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://kinoprofi.net/embed/9527">
    <meta property="og:video:iframe" content="http://kinoprofi.net/embed/9527">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:content_id" content="movie9527">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:allow_embed" content="true">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:adult" content="false">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:feed_url" content="http://kinoprofi.net/ovs/9527-palmy-v-snegu.xml">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:original_name" content="Palmeras en la nieve">
    <meta property="og:duration" content="9937">
    <meta property="video:duration" content="9937">
    <meta property="ya:ovs:upload_date" content="2016-04-16">
    <meta property="video:release_date" content="2015-12-09">
```

The begin of og: property is a video values. Where can I found the documentation of this meta codes?

**Please do not mark this question as duplicate, because others does not answered well.**

Comment: Can you detail what you have tried? Also, how is this question different from other possible duplicates?

Comment: See this for more about the og:video tag - http://searchengineland.com/use-open-graph-to-get-video-thumbnails-into-your-search-results-128264 - but it seems Google favours Youtube thumbnails now: https://wistia.com/blog/where-did-my-video-snippets-go

Answer (score 0):

og tags stands for Open Graph tags which is developed by Facebook. og tags are widely accepted meta tags concepts. You can find the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup